# How can I build and install a Qt project/.pro?

Tags: qt, install-from-source

I would like to install sqlite database browser from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

I downloaded the file and unzipped it with `tar -xvf sqlitebrowser_200_b1_src.tar.gz`

Now it's a directory in my downloads with this structure:

```
| -- trunk
     | -- sqlitebrowser
          | -- sqlite_source
          | -- images
          | .. lots of files
```

From here how do I install the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @Lucio it was not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The version on sourceforge is the same one available from repo on Trusty.  I can't verify older releases.

```
cd ~/
mkdir junk
cd junk
apt-get source sqlitebrowser
sudo apt-get install devscripts
sudo apt-get build-dep sqlitebrowser
cd sqlitebrowser-2.0.0~beta1+ds.1/
debuild -us -uc
```

There, you built it from source.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you can install it [building the source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), you may want to install using the Software Center, it's simpler. Search [`sqlitebrowser`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sqlitebrowser), click on *install* and done.

[image: search and install sqlitebrowser on the software center]

Answer (score 0):

It was an Qt project they use **qmake** (that comes with Qt development package) instead of configure.

"./configue" "make" "makeinstall"  none of them work with 
that.

Comment: Please, write the full set of commands to enter in order.

Answer (score 0):

as you have downloaded the .gz file already now just have to configure and install it do the following steps-

I am considering that its downloaded into Downloads folder under home-

```
cd Downloads
tar -xvf sqlitebrowser_200_b1_src.tar.gz
```

After that you will get one more folder , thats the extracted folder to check it  run-

```
ls -a
```

then use cd to enter in that extracted folder as-

```
cd name_of_extracted folder
```

then run the configure file as shown below-

```
./configure
```

and install it by using -

```
make
sudo make install
```

Thats it , if you will get any error paste it here in your question.

Comment: -1 without comment.. At least let me know whats the problem in my answer..

Comment: did you installed sqlitebrowser using this method?

Comment: no , but it was on internet, its a .bin file , its the  way to install as its not .gz , well am installing it now.. i will update it if needed or delete it if it wont work. but if someone is downvoting it . he should mention the reason.

Comment: yes,try that if it works then update your answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have tested this myself , now i can say it is not going to work as there is no config file under extrected trunk folder.. so its better to delete this answer. just wanted to tell you , reply then i will delete it.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that he saw it after your edit bump and copy paste from the canonical question..  just waiting.